# How to Not Run Unit Tests in Parallel Build & Release?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

isolation and/or non-parallel mode does not appear to be working properly. using TFS 2017 version 15.117.26714.0.

we run functional tests at night and we have some static methods that are conflicting. we use SQL CE and we create a temp database file and then execute sql scripts.

The tests run at the same time and some of the static objects are crossing over and using database file from the other test.  How can I get these tests to run in parallel so don't have these conflicts?

Unit Test 1 - creates a temp folder and temp db w/ unique GUID (cc4b3035-c4d0-48c4-92f6-15ccf3307cd7 in the log file below)

it does a bunch of stuff
at the end it cleans up by deleting the database
Unit Test 2 - creates its own temp folder & db w/ unique GUID (22842bcb-621a-46f5-84c4-df82b22a7dca in the log file below)

it is doing it's stuff, but then a db query uses the db path from Unit Test 1 and throws exception cos Unit Test 1 must have completed and deleted it's db:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = D:\agent1_work_temp*cc4b3035-c4d0-48c4-92f6-15ccf3307cd7*\DB.sdf ]

set to run in isolation on server and no parallel:
https://imgur.com/0QXdSG8
also did this in RunSettings but don't think that does much:

```
<MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
```

log file is 186 MB will not attach here. here is relevant info: (if you really want it let me know can zip it up etc.)

Unit Test #1 (this time it failed for an unrelated reason)

```
2017-10-20T10:08:11.6808584Z Failed ImportDefaultMixedAnimalHPTest
2017-10-20T10:08:11.6808584Z Error Message:
2017-10-20T10:08:11.6808584Z Test method Cuattro.Tests.Misc.DatabaseFunctionalTests.CreateDatabaseTests.ImportDefaultMixedAnimalHPTest threw exception:
2017-10-20T10:08:11.6808584Z System.Exception: ImportWarningAttentionRequest WarningImportingHangingProtocolItem
2017-10-20T10:08:11.6808584Z Stack Trace:
2017-10-20T10:08:11.6808584Z at Cuattro.Tests.Misc.DatabaseFunctionalTests.CreateDatabaseTests.ImportDefaultHPCore(HangingProtocolImportFile hangingProtocolImportFile) in D:\agent1_work\2\s\Dev\20170305_MD_4.4\Tests\Misc\DatabaseFunctionalTests\CreateDatabaseTests.cs:line 123
2017-10-20T10:08:11.6808584Z at Cuattro.Tests.Misc.DatabaseFunctionalTests.CreateDatabaseTests.ImportDefaultMixedAnimalHPTest() in D:\agent1_work\2\s\Dev\20170305_MD_4.4\Tests\Misc\DatabaseFunctionalTests\CreateDatabaseTests.cs:line 57

2017-10-20T10:08:13.9621426Z Debug Trace:
2017-10-20T10:08:13.9621426Z Cuattro.Tests.Misc.DatabaseFunctionalTests.CreateDatabaseTests: 2017-10-20 05:02:42,347 DEBUG (11)- ServiceLocatorHelper.CreateAndInitContainer()
2017-10-20T10:08:13.9621426Z Cuattro.Common.IOHelper: 2017-10-20 05:02:53,629 DEBUG (11)- GetTempFolder: D:\agent1_work_temp*cc4b3035-c4d0-48c4-92f6-15ccf3307cd7*
2017-10-20T10:08:13.9621426Z Created temp folder: D:\agent1_work_temp*cc4b3035-c4d0-48c4-92f6-15ccf3307cd7*, dir exists: True

...
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Cuattro.Misc.SqlCe.SqlCeDatabaseAdmin: 2017-10-20 05:08:04,305 DEBUG (11)- Shutdown
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Cuattro.Misc.SqlCe.ExtendedSqlCeDatabase: 2017-10-20 05:08:04,305 DEBUG (11)- CloseSharedConnection
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Cuattro.Tests.Misc.DatabaseFunctionalTests.ServiceLocatorHelper: 2017-10-20 05:08:04,368 DEBUG (11)- Deleting temp folder from appContext: D:\agent1_work_temp*cc4b3035-c4d0-48c4-92f6-15ccf3307cd7*
```

Unit Test #2 that fails because of missing file:

```
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Failed ImportDefaultHumanHPTest
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Error Message:
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Test method Cuattro.Tests.Misc.DatabaseFunctionalTests.CreateDatabaseTests.ImportDefaultHumanHPTest threw exception:
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = D:\agent1_work_temp*cc4b3035-c4d0-48c4-92f6-15ccf3307cd7*\DB.sdf ]

2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Debug Trace:
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Cuattro.Tests.Misc.DatabaseFunctionalTests.CreateDatabaseTests: 2017-10-20 05:08:11,665 DEBUG (11)- ServiceLocatorHelper.CreateAndInitContainer()
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Cuattro.Common.IOHelper: 2017-10-20 05:08:11,665 DEBUG (11)- GetTempFolder: D:\agent1_work_temp*22842bcb-621a-46f5-84c4-df82b22a7dca*
2017-10-20T10:08:45.5563686Z Created temp folder: D:\agent1_work_temp*22842bcb-621a-46f5-84c4-df82b22a7dca*, dir exists: True
```

Comment: Do you mean that some test will reference the data generated by another test, then in Parallel they will conflict as the data issue?

Comment: How about making the tests run in a certain sequential order? There is an **[Ordered Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** in VS which you can list tests in sequence.

Apart from that there are `Setup / TearDown` methods(`Setup = [TestInitialize]; TearDown = [TestCleanup]`) that can be used per test such that it may be possible to isolate the tests from each other.

Comment: andy thanks for response, well, both tests are using a sql ce database file, and some objects in one test are using a connection string to the other thing.  I can look into ordered test - but, how can i turn of parallel on the server?  can do it in vs.  and seems to be checkboxes for that but don't appear to work.  thanks.

Comment: Do you mean turn off it during the TFS building? If you are using VSTest task you can disable the `Run in parallel` option. Also you can try to
 introduce the `.runsettings` file. See [Parallel Test Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/) for more information.

Comment: andy, yes on TFS server.  thanks for link but that is what I specified in my original post.  despite not having parallel checked and specifying MaxCpuCount is 0, it still seems to be running in parallel and having these issues... why is it doing this, is this a bug?

Comment: Does it have the same issue if run the test in command line?